# C++ Multithreading objects from library with static variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, static, lib

I created several "manager" objects of a library, each with different parameters. Every cycle a manager is fed with a data set, run calculations and writes result into a data structure. I have to run all managers on the same data set as fast as possible, so I created a threadpool to distribute data to all managers so that they can be run concurrently. Each manager have access to one result data structure, so I thought this will be thread safe.

However later I found out that the several classes in this library, which are used by managers, have static member variables which (as I believe) causes segmentation faults - segmentation errors originates from the library, not my code (checked).

My question is, is it possible to go around this? This will probably sound stupid, but is it possible to force each manager to use its own copy of the library and thus circumventing the static issue? I am processing ~20-50k data sets per second so I cannot afford overhead. Using forks would be very painful and in my case could create unwanted overheads.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What operating system are you talking about? I do not see why forks are much overhead. If you create subprocesses at the beginning of your calculation you only have to create them once and the overhead is negligible.

Comment: Most likely not possible without forking new processes

Comment: I working on Linux (CentOS/Debian). The overhead would come from the need to consolidate the results by parent thread, at least it would in my current implementation. I guess I really have to rework the whole thing...